Fundamental group of the cube skeleton minus a point
I'm trying to do Exercise 10.10

Compute the fundamental group of the space $X$ that is the union of the edges of the cube $C = [0, 1]^3$. Moreover, compute the fundamental group of $X \setminus \{x\}$ as one varies $x \in X$.


The first part of the question: $X$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^2\setminus\text{6 points}$ (the 6 faces are holes), by the previous Exercise 10.9, $\pi_1(X)$ is the free group on 5 generators.
The second part of the question: What is the fundamental group of $X \setminus \{x\}$?

If $x$ is a vertex of $X$, collapsing the $3$ edges around $x$, we get $X \setminus \{x\}$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^2\setminus\text{4 points}$, so $\pi_1(X)$ is the free group on 3 generators.
If $x\in$ interior of an edge of $X$, collapsing this edge, we get $X \setminus \{x\}$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^2\setminus\text{5 points}$, so $\pi_1(X)$ is the free group on 4 generators.
